# How to get value of multiple fields in one Go using Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My requirement is to get the count of particular values from repository and store it in response class ,for each field I am querying each and everytime ,

simply if it is first iteration set in countofData1 if its second then set in countofdata2 and further

same goes further ,
how to set the values in each case efficiently

```
Response.java

private int  countOfData1;
private int  countOfData2;
private int  countOfDat3;
```

origin has values of  = ["data1","data2","data3"]

```
public static List<Response> value(String id,List<String> origin){
    for (String s : origin) {
         Response response  = new Response();
           List<String> countOfData1 = repo.findCountbyData1(id ,s);
           response.setCountOfData1(countOfData1,size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could improve the code by fixing the indentation etc :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without making any assumptions about the repository & assuming that you're referring to a solution involving concurrency, you can use parallel streams (or sequential Java streams if you don't want concurrency) if you are using Java 8+.

```
List<Response> listOfResponse = origin.parallelStream().map(s -> {
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setCountOfData1(repo.findCountbyData1(id ,s),size();
    response.setCountOfData2(repo.findCountbyData2(id ,s),size();
    response.setCountOfData3(repo.findCountbyData3(id ,s),size();
    return response;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
return listOfResponse;
```

[This Spring doc has examples for both uses](https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream)

Comment: but what if we want to set countofData2 and countofdata3 , how can we use this chunk there

Comment: I was working off of the example you provided. Can you be more explicit about what you want to do with countOfData2 and countOfData3? It's not clear what those variables are for.

Comment: Question edited please check

Comment: I updated the answer, but I think you need to check your original code logic. In your original code you are executing `repo.findCountbyData1(id ,"data1");`, `repo.findCountbyData1(id ,"data2");`, and `repo.findCountbyData1(id ,"data3");` which I'm not sure makes sense.
In any case, that's irrelevant since the original question was answered & the question wasn't about the correctness about the code.